# Bind listview to config sourced property

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm attempting to follow the guide to try to persist multiple choices from two lists to config. (https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part2/Config%20Settings%20and%20State.html). The guide only discusses SimpleStringProperty in this context. I can see that I should be using SimpleListProperty, but I don't see the right way to associate it with config.

My rough attempt so far:

```
data class Devices(val receivers: List<String>, val transmitters: List<String>)


// XXX I'd like to just persist Devices, but I'm exposing separate properties for the constituents of Devices
class DevicesModel: ItemViewModel<Devices>() {

    // XXX type ends up as Property<ObservableList<JsonValue>>, which seems wrong
    val receivers = bind { SimpleListProperty(this, "receivers", config.jsonArray("receivers")!!.toObservable()) }

    val transmitters = bind { SimpleListProperty(this, "transmitters", config.jsonArray("transmitters")!!.toObservable()) }    

}

class FooView: View() {

    val devicesModel = DevicesModel()

    // XXX this wants a ReadOnlyListProperty, rather than what it's getting
    fun receivers() = listview<String>(devicesModel.receivers) {
        selectionModel.selectionMode = SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
    }

    fun transmitters() = listview<String>(devicesModel.transmitters) {
        selectionModel.selectionMode = SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
    }

}
```

Obviously I haven't tackled commit etc, which I will. My question is about the binding/association specifically -- where have I gone wrong? My lack of JavaFX / UI programming background is probably hurting me here.

I have three questions marked with XXX in code, specifically:

- I have a mismatch between the properties I'm exposing and the data class. I suppose this could be dealt with in the commit, but that seems messy.
- The typing on the properties themselves (particularly JsonValue being exposed) seems wrong, but I don't see a way to expose what I'm looking for.
- Why does `listview()` want a ReadOnlyListProperty? How do I make this accept an Observable?

I will post a PR to the guide with an example, and some clarifying explanation, once I get this working.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not well versed in how the config thing works but what I do know is that you are trying to put list properties of type `<JsonValue!>` while you've specifically typed your ListViews as type `<String>`. Your IDE is slightly misleading you. It's simply asking that the minimum that it needs is a read-only list property **of the correct type**. If you want that type to be displayed in a certain way, inside the listview builder, use: `cellFormat {  text = /* it.whateveryouwant */ }`

Comment: You've also failed to override the View's root, but maybe you excluded that from your example on purpose. Why are your listviews generated by functions? Do you plan to generate them multiple times in the same view?

Comment: @JCamacho - true, yes, the root is being composed elsewhere that I didn't include in source. They don't really need to be functions; I just broke them out so that I could compose the root view in a few lines. (They should probably be vals.)